# QML Cannot emit signal if it has same name as property

Tags: qt, qml

I was trying to wrap a `MouseArea` to customise it's behaviour and came across a strange issue.  The example code below demonstrates the problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Item {
    id: base
    width: 100
    height: 100
    anchors.fill: parent

    property alias pressed: area.pressed

    signal pressed( var mouse )

    MouseArea {
        id: area
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            base.pressed( mouse );
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking in the rectangle results in this error:

> TypeError: Property 'pressed' of object QmlTest_QMLTYPE_0(0x1b4c780) is not a function

Clearly it's trying to call the property `pressed` rather than the signal `pressed`.  Is there a workaround for this?  Bear in mind that the interface has to mimic `MouseArea` so there needs to be a both a `pressed` property *and* signal.

This does strike me as a bug, as clearly `MouseArea` manages it, but it is declared from C++.  I know that the usual answer to any slightly complex QML question is "do it in C++", but because the great majority of QtQuick classes are private, it's usually not practical.

Comment: Does your type have to be a registered, importable QML type, or can it be a context property?

Comment: In a normal application I would envisage my type being instantiated in many places with different parameters, so I doubt a context property would be practical.  But please share your idea if it could be an effective workaround for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've already answered the question yourself. I doubt that there's a workaround in QML for this, and the answer probably is "do it in C++" - I can't say for sure though.

Here's how you can do it in C++, defining a `QQuickItem` that creates the `MouseArea` internally using `QQmlComponent`:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtQuick>

class CustomMouseArea : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool pressed READ pressed NOTIFY pressedChanged)
public:
    CustomMouseArea() :
        mMouseArea(0)
    {
    }

    // Can't use constructor, as we don't have a QQmlContext by that stage.
    void componentComplete() {
        QQmlComponent component(qmlEngine(this), QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///InternalMouseArea.qml")));
        if (component.status() != QQmlComponent::Ready) {
            qDebug() << component.errorString();
            return;
        }

        mMouseArea = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component.create());
        Q_ASSERT(mMouseArea);
        mMouseArea->setParentItem(this);

        connect(mMouseArea, SIGNAL(pressedChanged()), this, SIGNAL(pressedChanged()));

        // Don't forget to call the base class' implementation, or no child items will show up! :)
        QQuickItem::componentComplete();
    }

    bool pressed() const {
        return mMouseArea->property("pressed").toBool();
    }
signals:
    void pressedChanged();
private:
    QQuickItem *mMouseArea;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<CustomMouseArea>("Test", 1, 0, "CustomMouseArea");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

#### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

import Test 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: "green"
    visible: true

    CustomMouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressedChanged: print("pressed =", pressed)
    }
}
```

#### InternalMouseArea.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

At first I used the constructor to create the `MouseArea` and wondered why I had a null `QQmlEngine`, and then discovered that it's [documented not to have a context at that stage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#details):

> Note that these functions will return null when called inside the constructor of a QObject subclass, as the instance will not yet have a context nor engine.

The only problem is the [pressed signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#pressed-signal) of `MouseArea`; its `MouseEvent` parameter is [private API](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/5a9f0131f8c0b7424a4d323b0f65237206be45ea:src/quick/items/qquickevents_p_p.h#L100). You might be able to encapsulate that class somehow and provide users with a JavaScript object that contains all of its properties, but it seems like it would be easier just to use private API at this point.

Comment: Ah, I just realised that I forgot about the pressed() signal with its event parameter...